# How can I display a value of an Java Integer?

Tags: java, android

Hi I´m new to Android Studio. I searched the whole internet for a solution. 
I want to display a value of a variable which I can constantly change. My first Idea was to create a variable in Java whose value i can hand over to the xml code. But everything I tried didn´t function.

Here´s my code:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text=""
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="124dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="53dp" />
```

Java:

```
public static int money = 5;
public static TextView moneyNumber;
```

I declared the variables on top of my class

```
public void setNumber(View v) {
    moneyNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    moneyNumber.setText(money+" ");
}
```

Comment: "But everything I tried didn´t function". Pls elaborate or post some more relevant code.

Comment: "_I searched the whole internet_" That is quite impressive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're giving the `moneyNumber.setText()` an int instead of a charsequence. The function does accept integers but it expects it to be a resource identifier.

Use this instead

```
public void setNumber(View v) {
    moneyNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    moneyNumber.setText(String.valueOf(money));
}
```

Comment: I added it to my code but on my mobile there was no number displayed

Comment: This is certainly setting the text, if you're not seeing the number there's something else going wrong. We can only help you if you're more specific about what the issue is.